# Outlook 2007: Is there a keyboard shortcut for Find text in an email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Pressing "Ctrl+F" would forward the message. Then, is there a keyboard shortcut for finding text in an email? (Think Adobe PDF Ctrl+F or Word Ctrl+F)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:  To search *within* an e-mail, `ALT+HFD` will bring up the Find dialog without having to add it to the Quick Access Toolbar.

---

Back when I thought you were asking about searching through e-mail items in Outlook:

From your Inbox just hit `Ctrl+E`.  This will focus the Instant Search box for searching the contents of e-mail.  Alternately, `Ctrl+Alt+A` will focus the search box for Search All Mail Items.

[image: Instant Search]

Comment: ALT+HFD or ALT+6 :-)

Answer (score 11):

The F4 key will also bring up the Find and Replace dialog for searching in a message.

Comment: this works only when the message is already open in its own window :-/ but thank you better than nothing :-)

Answer (score 3):

While you have a message open. In the upper right hand is a "Find" button. Right click it and add to quick access toolbar. Then press ALT+6 or whatever number outlook has assigned to the button.

Comment: Your answer is very succinct, and works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The F4 key is the one you want.

It will find a particular word (or part of a word) within the text/body of an e-mail.

Every time you hit the Enter key after that, it will find the next word or part.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be by default.

If you hover over the Find option the tooltip just reads:

> **Find**
>
> Find text in the document

If you hover over the Replace option you get:

> **Replace (Ctrl+H)**
>
> Replace text in the document